# How to measure euclidean distance between points with vtkDelaunay3D package?

Tags: python, delaunay-triangulation, vtk

I'm working with python vtkDelaunay3D package for a special purpose. I have set some points but I do not know how can I measure euclidean distance between points with this package. Is there anyone who knows measuring euclidean distance between points with this package in python?

Comment: Please don't cross-post: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2452/how-to-measure-euclidean-distance-between-points-with-vtkdelaunay3d-package